# How to configure Hadoop 2.2 to fit this situation?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have installed the `hadoop 2.2` with four machines. They are:

```
  namenodes: master1,master2
  datanodes: slave1,slave2
```

The `master1` is installed on my notebook, and I want to close the `master1` when I sleep. And
when the `master1` is in the `active` state, the `master2` is in the `standby` state. When I close my notebook, will the hadoop cluster automatically change the active namenode to the `master2`?

I don't know if I understand the meaning of hadoop v2's `multiple namenodes`. Does the feature  fit my situation described above? Thanks.

Comment: when you say multiple namenodes, you mean its configured for hdfs federation?

Comment: Yes, sir. I mean this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the High Availability feature for the NameNodes.  When it detects the Primary NameNode going offline, the Secondary will automatically take over.

There will be a brief hiccup in the operation of the cluster, however, as the Secondary node will delay in responding to block location requests for a short amount of time (30 to 60 seconds usually), giving all Data nodes enough time to point to the new NN.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You are right, maybe I should wait for a few minutes to check the `standby` namenode to be active.

Comment: Just make sure you've configured the Name Nodes in High Availability mode.  A basic Name Node configuration won't failover ... please read [High Availability With Quorum Journal Manager](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html).

Comment: OK, sir. I just found the wrong documentation. The webpage is right. I'll try it. Thanks.